# Jquery Datatables Colvis fires preDrawCallback and DrawCallback twice on column item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Please refer to my test case

https://jsfiddle.net/1c3Lmace/13/

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        "fnPreDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
          alert('pre');
        },
        "fnDrawCallback" : function() {
          alert('+++++');
        }
    } );
} );
```

When you go to Show/Hide Columns and click on any column item you will see that each preDrawCallBack and drawCallback event fires twice.

Does anyone having any idea why it happens.

I want to show a loader before data loads and hide it and when data is successfully loaded. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why you need fnPreDrawCallback?

Comment: How can I show loader before data load then?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the events are fired twice but only when sorted column visibility is being toggled.

I see no point in showing loading indicator for client-side processing, column visibility changes occur very fast. For server-side processing, there is [`processing`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing) option already available.

You can do something like this. But I had to put an `alert()` because columns are toggled very fast and `Processing...` message disappears quickly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        processing: true,
        drawCallback : function() {
          $('.dataTables_processing', $('#example').DataTable().table().container()).hide();
        }
    } );
} );

$('#example').on( 'column-visibility.dt', function ( e, settings, column, state ) {
    $('.dataTables_processing', $('#example').DataTable().table().container()).show();
    alert('Column visibility is toggled');
} );
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1c3Lmace/15/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I need a loading feature as in Internet Explorer when records become very large, the click on Colvis stucks for some time , and sometimes the javascript error came, that script is taking too much time to execute

Comment: Sorry @Gyrocode.com, but this doesn't  solve my issue, as the column is hiding first and then the alert is coming. I want opposite to it.